# MemoryError vs "ValueError: array is too big" when allocating a large ndarray on different machines

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, memory-management

I am running Python on two separate devices—MacBook Air mid-2013 (Laptop 1) and ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3G (Laptop 2)—and creating numpy arrays on both. Despite the two laptops having relatively similar memory:

Laptop 1: Memory 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Laptop 2: Installed RAM 16.0 GB (15.8 GB usable)

I am finding wildly different threshold array sizes on the two laptops before observing a `MemoryError`. For example:

**Laptop 1**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros(int(5.*10.**12))
array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> np.zeros(int(6.*10.**12))
Python(6138,0x7fffda9413c0) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=48000000000000) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

**Laptop 2**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros(int(1.*10.**8.))
array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> np.zeros(int(5.*10.**8.))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
>>> np.zeros(int(5.*10.**9.))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Maximum allowed dimension exceeded
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros(int(1.*10.**8.))
array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> np.zeros(int(5.*10.**8.))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
>>> np.zeros(int(5.*10.**9.))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Maximum allowed dimension exceeded
```

**Linux:**

```
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:16:44) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros(int(5.*10.**8))
array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> np.zeros(int(5.*10.**9))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Therefore an array of length (approximately) 5 trillion appears to be Laptop 1's limit before receiving a `MemoryError`, while Laptop 2's threshold is closer to about 0.5 billion. This is essentially a disparity of 4 orders of magnitude, yet the available memory on each laptop is not nearly that different. I also tried creating similar arrays on two Linux machines with about 4 GB of RAM each and observed a length of approximately 1.0 billion to be the limit.

I am clearly missing something perhaps obvious. Any clarity into the situation of why this disparity is observed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're getting `ValueError: array is too big; arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize is larger than the maximum possible size.` rather than `MemoryError` at the 2nd machine, the reason must be Python or numpy's architectural limitation at that machine rather than system memory limitations.

**Most probably, you're using 32-bit Python at the 2nd machine**: [searching the error message in `numpy`'s codebase](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?q=%22array%20is%20too%20big%22&unscoped_q=%22array%20is%20too%20big%22) shows that [this error is raised when calculating array size results in integer overflow](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/15b092f5541e80d7c3d0108957406c6f8686aba0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L994).

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have included an additional example where `MemoryError` is observed.