# GaussianProcessRegressor ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I am running the following code:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct, WhiteKernel
print(X.shape)
print(X.values[:,list_of_relevant_features].dtype)
print(y.values.dtype)
kernel = DotProduct() + WhiteKernel()
model_gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=42)
model_gp.fit(X.values[:,list_of_relevant_features], y.values)
print("GP: R2 score: ", model_gp.score(X.values[:,list_of_relevant_features], y.values))
```

The shape of my input is:
`(19142, 21)`
dtypes are each: `float64`

Added in Edit:
X and y are Pandas Dataframes.
After `.values` they're each numpy arrays

And I get the Error:

`` ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size. ``

I cant image a dataset of 20000 * 20 to be actually too big for gaussian processes, am I wrong?

The entire error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
filepath in 
      482 kernel = DotProduct() + WhiteKernel()
      483 model_gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=42)
----> 484 model_gp.fit(X.values[:,list_of_relevant_features], y.values)
      485 print("GP: R2 score: ", model_gp.score(X.values[:,list_of_relevant_features], y.values))
      486 

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\_gpr.py in fit(self, X, y)
    238             optima = [(self._constrained_optimization(obj_func,
    239                                                       self.kernel_.theta,
--> 240                                                       self.kernel_.bounds))]
    241 
    242             # Additional runs are performed from log-uniform chosen initial

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\_gpr.py in _constrained_optimization(self, obj_func, initial_theta, bounds)
    503             opt_res = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    504                 obj_func, initial_theta, method="L-BFGS-B", jac=True,
--> 505                 bounds=bounds)
    506             _check_optimize_result("lbfgs", opt_res)
    507             theta_opt, func_min = opt_res.x, opt_res.fun

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    616     elif meth == 'l-bfgs-b':
    617         return _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 618                                 callback=callback, **options)
    619     elif meth == 'tnc':
    620         return _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, callback=callback,

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)
    306     sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
    307                                   bounds=new_bounds,
--> 308                                   finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step)
    309 
    310     func_and_grad = sf.fun_and_grad

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args, bounds, epsilon, finite_diff_rel_step, hess)
    260     # calculation reduces overall function evaluations.
    261     sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
--> 262                         finite_diff_rel_step, bounds, epsilon=epsilon)
    263 
    264     return sf

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in __init__(self, fun, x0, args, grad, hess, finite_diff_rel_step, finite_diff_bounds, epsilon)
     74 
     75         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun
---> 76         self._update_fun()
     77 
     78         # Gradient evaluation

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in _update_fun(self)
    164     def _update_fun(self):
    165         if not self.f_updated:
--> 166             self._update_fun_impl()
    167             self.f_updated = True
    168 

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in update_fun()
     71 
     72         def update_fun():
---> 73             self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)
     74 
     75         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in fun_wrapped(x)
     68         def fun_wrapped(x):
     69             self.nfev += 1
---> 70             return fun(x, *args)
     71 
     72         def update_fun():

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in __call__(self, x, *args)
     72     def __call__(self, x, *args):
     73         """ returns the the function value """
---> 74         self._compute_if_needed(x, *args)
     75         return self._value
     76 

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in _compute_if_needed(self, x, *args)
     66         if not np.all(x == self.x) or self._value is None or self.jac is None:
     67             self.x = np.asarray(x).copy()
---> 68             fg = self.fun(x, *args)
     69             self.jac = fg[1]
     70             self._value = fg[0]

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\_gpr.py in obj_func(theta, eval_gradient)
    229                 if eval_gradient:
    230                     lml, grad = self.log_marginal_likelihood(
--> 231                         theta, eval_gradient=True, clone_kernel=False)
    232                     return -lml, -grad
    233                 else:

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\_gpr.py in log_marginal_likelihood(self, theta, eval_gradient, clone_kernel)
    460 
    461         if eval_gradient:
--> 462             K, K_gradient = kernel(self.X_train_, eval_gradient=True)
    463         else:
    464             K = kernel(self.X_train_)

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\kernels.py in __call__(self, X, Y, eval_gradient)
    813         if eval_gradient:
--> 814             K1, K1_gradient = self.k1(X, Y, eval_gradient=True)
    815             K2, K2_gradient = self.k2(X, Y, eval_gradient=True)
    816             return K1 + K2, np.dstack((K1_gradient, K2_gradient))

d:\Toms_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\kernels.py in __call__(self, X, Y, eval_gradient)
   2110         X = np.atleast_2d(X)
   2111         if Y is None:
-> 2112             K = np.inner(X, X) + self.sigma_0 ** 2
   2113         else:
   2114             if eval_gradient:

<__array_function__ internals> in inner(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Comment: 19142 times 21 times 8 (bytes for double floating point precision) is a bit over 3 MB, so definitely not overly large. There may be some copying, but I can't imagine this being a problem (also given that there is no OutOfMemoryError).

Comment: Sure. Both are Pandas dataframes. Only numeric obviously

Comment: Mybad. both are numpy arrays, since I used `.values` dtype `float64`

Comment: `y.shape` = `(19142,)`

Comment: In my actual code the line is as follows: `super_long_df.values[:,only_the_columns_I_want_to_train_on]`, so I got a dataframe, but the gausian process receives a numpy array. I only wrote X to simplify unneccesarry information

Comment: The other information that is likely needed is about the system you are trying to run this on: what is the operating system, and more importantly, what type of (CPU) hardware? Is it 32 bits or 64 bits, specifically? Also, what is the amount of memory in your system?

Comment: The system is quite powerfull and 64 bit. The python installation however is only 32bit.

Comment: I also edited the question once more to clean up the df and np.array situation

Comment: I'm not familiar with running 32 bit Python under bit 64 Windows, but that might just be the problem. If you can, see if you can install and use a 64 bit Python version instead. From a quick test with variables of the given shape, the fit allocates quite a bit of extra memory, which for me is well of 2GB. Which could be a problem for a 32 bit version and its addressable memory.

Comment: I have trained other models with 10 times the size using other predictors.

Comment: Those other preditors may be more memory efficient, and not allocate a lot of extra memory. Try running your code with a smaller dataset (that actually runs), and monitor your memory consumption. See if the memory consumption is relatively high, and see if it crashes when our data size gets larger again (and total memory is e.g. more than 2 GB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this happened because of the dot product kernel: The traceback in line 2112 leads to the `numpy` [inner product](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html). So, the memory error you get actually [arises in `numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/15b092f5541e80d7c3d0108957406c6f8686aba0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L994) and not in `Scikit-learn`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072697/memoryerror-vs-valueerror-array-is-too-big-when-allocating-a-large-ndarray-on) SO question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55072945/4467226) where it suggests that error is raised when `numpy` is calculating the expected array size of the result of the inner prosuct which could lead to an integer overflow in 32-bit Python. My python setup is 64-bit so I can't do a consistent test but the following snippet runs without error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct, WhiteKernel
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

b = load_boston()

X = [pd.DataFrame(b['data'])]
y = b['target']
for i in range(50):
    X.append(pd.DataFrame(b['data']))
    y = np.append(y,b['target'])
    
X = pd.concat(X)
X = pd.concat([X,X[X.columns[0:8]]],axis=1)
print(X.values.shape,y.shape)

kernel = DotProduct() + WhiteKernel()
model_gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=42)
model_gp.fit(X.values, y)
```

I would suggest running your model with less features in order to see at which array shape the memory error is raised. Alternatively you may try different kernels that don't require the inner product of `X`.

Comment: Thank you and yes. It appears to be a kernel problem. This acctually caused me to rethink the fact i am using 32bit. Hopefully the problem will resolve itself, with 64bit.